# How to output the full page URL?

Tags: siteurl

Very simple request!
All I want to do is to be able to get the full URL of the page & output that in the HTML (for a 'share this page' link).
Can anyone help please?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Craft 3 and 4**

In Craft 3 and 4 this is now `{{ craft.app.request.absoluteUrl }}` — for those who land here from a search and want to avoid using the deprecation notice to update it! (see answer from @natebeaty)

And in case you are looking for more options like `{{ craft.app.request.pathInfo }}` to get current url path, look up the Craft 3 [Craft Web Request Class](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-request.html#public-properties)

**Craft 2**

```
{{ craft.request.getUrl() }}
```

or

```
{{ craft.request.url }}
```

If you need to include the query string (like `?foo=bar`), this should do it:

```
{{ craft.request.getHostInfo() ~ craft.request.getRequestUri() }}
```

Beyond that, `craft.request` is mapped to the [HttpRequestVariable class](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-httprequestvariable.html), which contain a plethora of methods and properties to render information about the current request.

Comment: In Craft 2 you can use `{{ url('/page') }}` in Twig or `\Craft\UrlHelper::getUrl('/page')` in PHP to get an absolute URL for a given path.

Answer (score 28):

In Craft 3 this is now `{{ craft.app.request.absoluteUrl }}` — for those who land here from a search and want to avoid using the deprecation notice to update it!

Comment: Any way to exclude query strings?

Comment: Not sure if there's a more elegant way (I couldn't find anything digging around, closest was `craft.app.request.fullPath`), but this does the trick: `craft.app.request.absoluteUrl|replace('?'~craft.app.request.queryStringWithoutPath,'')`

Comment: Try using the built in URL helper, like so `{{ url(craft.app.request.fullPath) }}` to remove the query string

Answer (score 6):

In Craft 3 and PHP you can use `\Craft::$app->getRequest()->absoluteUrl` or `\Craft::$app->request->absoluteUrl`